# Windows: How can I use the command line to set registry permissions

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

OS: Windows 7
Desirable Method: Command Line
Other acceptable methods: VBScript

How can I use the command line to set registry permissions? I found the [REGINI utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/237607), but I'm not having any luck since the documentation is really not user-friendly. I need to set the permissions on the following to prevent the user from editing. Basically, I need to set this as read-only:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData

The ideal permissions would allow SYSTEM and Administrator Full Control, but set as Read Only for everyone else (or at least non-Admins).

For a little background, this is where, in IE 11 the Compatibility View sites are held (in binary nonetheless). I'm injecting that binary glob, but because we have the option set in IE to clear browsing history upon exit, that 'ClearableListData' value is also purged. Stupid, I know, so I need to prevent users from modifying the value.

EDIT: Here's a Connect post describing the problem of IE purging the list: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/798447/compatibility-view-list-is-lost-if-browsing-history-is-erased-or-site-uses-meta-tag

Thanks,
Beems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

The *correct* way to lock down this setting is to use Group Policy.  You don't mention if this computer is on a domain or not, but if it isn't, you can use the Local Group Policy Editor for the same effect.  Click on Start -> Run and type `gpedit.msc` to open the editor.

The specific setting you're after is under `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Compatibility View`.  The setting is called `Use Policy list of Internet Explorer 7 sites`.

The sites that appear on this list will always open in Compatibility View, and doing a browser reset will not change that setting at all.  The setting survives because enforced Group Policies are located in a different place in the Registry and are unaffected by the bug listed in that Microsoft article you linked to.

Comment: I have tested this using local Group Policy, and it appears to suffer from the same problem. After configuring the sites, logging back in as the user, and closing the browser back out, the sites are gone again. I will test this again tomorrow morning though with a fresh set of eyes, because it's possible I inadvertently didn't 'Apply' the GPO setting before closing out.

Comment: Yes and it's easy to get wrong too (you have to hit enter before you hit the apply button).  I just attempted to fact-check myself (to see if maybe I am wrong about this), but I realized that I do not have a VM that isn't on a domain, so I will have to take a look tomorrow as well.

Comment: OK, so after watching the save of the GPO with Process Monitor (from MSFT/Sysinternals), it does appear to save the settings. However, I can't be convinced they're actually applying because when you open Compatibility View settings the sites specified via GPO don't appear in the list. I'm not sure how to otherwise check if they're **actually** applying since I can't seem to find a way to verify.

Comment: @Beems; If you head over to http://www.whatismybrowser.com, it will tell you that version of IE you're using.  So to check the group policy setting, add that site to the list, apply it, and then go to the web site again.  It should specifically tell you that your browser is in compatibility mode if the policy is working.

Comment: Group Policy settings work, thank you. I used to do it via GPO for IE9, but another Stack Exchange post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770933/how-can-i-programmatically-add-website-to-compatibility-list-internet-explorer-1) pointed me in the wrong direction. While the accepted solution works, it is affected by deleting the Temporary Internet Files. The same registry settings applied in the GPO as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\PolicyList\somewebsite.com` still work fine. Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction.

Comment: In IE9 that policy setting made this list visible and grayed out in the Compatibility View settings. I've just always been accustomed to seeing it that way.  In IE11 (or maybe 10) they changed the behavior so that nothing from the GPO shows in the list and the user is free to edit it. So when I saw that, I was worried for a while that I had given you bad advice. :-)  I'm glad you got it to work.

Comment: On a side note, I wrote a VBScript a long time ago that modified registry permissions in the HKCU hive.  I dug up the code for you this morning, but when I looked it over... Turns out I just made a call out to REGINI. LOL